# ¿Cómo utilizar librerias externas en reactjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jsx

Estoy teniendo muchos problemas en adecuarme al trabajo con `Reactjs` ya que anteriormente solo utilizaba `JQuery`.

En este momento intento utilizar la librería [autoNumeric.js](http://autonumeric.org/) el cual me ayuda a dar formato a los números. En `Jquery` lo utilizaba así:

```
$("#porciento").autoNumeric("init", {pSign:'s',aSign:' %',mDec: '2',aSep:'',vMin: '0', vMax: '99999'})
```

Pero ahora no me funciona, si lo utilizo así:

```
<script src="{{asset('assets/js/autonumeric/autoNumeric.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>//archivo reactjs compilado con npm run dev
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#porciento").autoNumeric("init", {pSign:'s',aSign:' %',mDec: '2',aSep:'',vMin: '0', vMax: '99999'});        
    });
</script>
```

Me sale un error en consola:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autoNumeric is not a function

Aunque el archivo está correctamente direccionado.

Intenté poniéndolo en la función `componentDidMount`:

```
async componentDidMount(){
    try{
        let res = await fetch(`${url}/api/sustancia`)
        let data = await res.json()
        $("#porciento").autoNumeric("init", {pSign:'s',aSign:' %',mDec: '2',aSep:'',vMin: '0', vMax: '99999'})
        this.setState({
            sustancias:data,
        })
    }
    catch(error){
        this.setState({
            error:error
        })
    }
}
```

En este caso no obtengo ningún error pero el `input` no funciona como debería.

Mi `JSX` es algo largo, así que solo publico el input:

```
<input type="text" 
    className="form-control" 
    name="porciento" 
    id="porciento" 
    required="required" 
    placeholder="0,8%" 
    value={form.porciento}
    onChange={onChange}
    />
```

Entonces ahora **no sé** si tendré otros problemas con otras librerías que solía utilizar, cabe aclarar que utilizo `Laravel` quizá tenga algo que ver.

Comment: @PabloLozano, una ayuda por aqui por favor.

Comment: No se si esto te sirva y tampoco se si sea la mejor solucion, pero en angular también tuve el mismo problema , solo agregue esto declare **var $: any;** en el component y ya tomo las funciones como se debe.

Comment: Creo que hay una libreria compatible con React https://www.npmjs.com/package/autonumeric, puedes mirar si te sirve

Comment: @Shassain no uses jquery si vas a utilizar react, angular, vuejs u otro framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dices que obtienes tu archivo `app.js` que compilaste con `npm`. Tomando esto en cuenta, la recomendación principal es que **no mezcles jQuery con otras tecnologías**, comprueba si hay implementaciones de lo que quieras hacer como componentes de la nueva tecnología que estás usando. En este caso, la hay aquí como **[react-numeric](https://github.com/mkg0/react-numeric)**.

Lo primero que debes hacer es, en la carpeta donde compilas tu app, abrir una línea de comandos y ejecutar la siguiente línea:

```
npm install react-numeric --save
```

Y en el archivo del componente donde lo quieras utilizar, debes incluir la cabecera

```
import ReactNumeric from 'react-numeric';
```

y lo incluyes así:

```
<ReactNumeric
  value={this.state.value}
  currencySymbol="$"
  minimumValue="0"
  decimalCharacter="."
  digitGroupSeparator=""
  onChange={(event, value)=>{
    console.log(event.target.value); // '1,234.5 $'
    console.log(value); // 1234.5
  }}
/>
```

Este proyecto en particular no incluye mucha documentación, pero no deberías tener cambios en cuanto a las propiedades con las que *inicializas* normalmente en jQuery. La lista completa de propiedades (o configuraciones) y los valores por defecto se incluyen en su [código fuente](https://github.com/mkg0/react-numeric/blob/master/src/index.js).

Finalmente, revisa también si no te faltará incluir el archivo `vendors.bundle.js` en tu HTML.

Comment: Entonces tendria que buscar mis librerias e instalarlas con `npm`, para poder usarlos. Lo intentare y te aviso como me va.

Comment: @Shassain Es la recomendación, no hay sustitutos en todos los casos pero hay muchas bibliotecas que ya no dependen de jQuery para funcionar.